# Leiningen 1.3 Upgrade Plugin Classpath

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a plugin that used to use command-line from contrib with the following in ns,

```
(:use  [leiningen.compile :only [eval-in-project]]
       [clojure.contrib command-line logging])
```

that used to work, I am guessing since leiningen also uses clojure and contrib it is automatically on its classpath with the new contrib structure above becomes,

```
(:use  [leiningen.compile :only [eval-in-project]]
       [clojure.tools cli logging])
```

it seems leiningen does not include jars from the lib/ on its class path and this fails, is there a workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Right. Unless you use `eval-in-project`, your code runs in Leiningen's classpath. Any code on lein's classpath is thus available to your project. These, however, are not.

Is the code that uses cli and logging inside of the eval-in-project call? If so, those jars need to be dependencies on the projects that you call the plugin in, and the `use` call must be passed to eval-in-project (see the documentation of eval-in-project for more info).

If the code that uses cli and logging is not inside of an eval-in-project call, then you can add those dependencies to your plugin project and it should just work. If you try to test the plugin inside of the plugin project itself, you'll need to add `:eval-in-leiningen true` to your project.clj.

If this doesn't help, please expand your question with more details/code.